# I'm trying to get this cursor effect on react

Tags: jquery, reactjs, mouseevent

I'm new to react and I'm trying to get this cursor effect on my landing page, but I haven't been able to make it without using jquery... I have looked at react [SyntheticEvents](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#mouse-events), but I don't know how to use them right.

Here is the effect that I want to achieve, but in react:

```js
$(document)
  .mousemove(function(e) {
    $('.cursor')
      .eq(0)
      .css({
        left: e.pageX,
        top: e.pageY
      });
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.cursor')
        .eq(1)
        .css({
          left: e.pageX,
          top: e.pageY
        });
    }, 100);
  })
```

```css
body{
  background:black;
}

h1{
  color:white;
}

* {
    cursor: none;
}

.cursor {
    position: fixed;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    pointer-events:none;
}
.cursors .cursor:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #3a26fd;
    z-index: 100002;
}
.cursors .cursor:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    z-index: 100001;
    height: 9px;
    width: 9px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cursors">
<div class='cursor'></div>
<div class='cursor'></div>
<div class='cursor'></div>
</div>
<h1>Custom cursor</h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a couple of notes:

I'm assuming you use Babel to transpile JSX and to be able to use ES2015 arrow functions. If not, please update your question and I'll update my answer.

Next, you don't need three elements of the *cursor* class. The code suggests you only use two elements. The blue one which I'll call **mainCursor** and the white one - **trailingCursor**.

Also, I didn't implement the eq function from jQuery, but in this example we are sure **document.getElementByClassName** will return 2 elements, so I'm not including checks for null.

---

The React way of implementing requested behavior is:

1. Create a *cursor* element that uses the position saved in **state** to render itself
2. Attach onMouseMove listener to the parent element inside which the mouse is moved
3. When the mouse is moved it will call the handler function, inside which we save the mouse position in **state** using **setState**, which triggers a rerender of the *cursor* element using the new mouse position

That being said, here's the ported version of the functionality from your question. I've provided a runnable snippet.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  // we keep track of x and y coordinates for the blue circle - the main one
  // and the trailing circle - the white one
  // for simplicity, they are initialzed to (0, 0), the top left corner of the viewport
  state = {
    xMain: 0,
    yMain: 0,
    xTrailing: 0,
    yTrailing: 0,
  }
  
  handleMouseMove = (e) => {
    // Using pageX and pageY will cause glitching when you scroll the window down
    // because it measures the distance from the top left rendered corner, not
    // top left visible corner
    const { clientX, clientY } = e;

    // we set the main circle coordinates as soon as the mouse is moved
    this.setState({
      xMain: clientX,
      yMain: clientY,
    }, () => {
      // this callback is invoked after the first setState finishes
      // 
      // here we schedule saving the trailing coordinates in state 100ms  
      // after the main coordinates have been set to simulate the trailing
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
          xTrailing: clientX,
          yTrailing: clientY,
        })
      }, 100);
    })
  }

  render = () => {
    // we retrieve coordinates from state
    const {
      xMain,
      yMain,
      xTrailing,
      yTrailing
    } = this.state;

    return (
      // we need a container that has a definite height, 800px in my example
      // this is to make sure it leaves enough room for mouse movement to happen and trigger the event handler
      // 
      // also, you don't need the event listener on both your cursor elements, only on the container
      <div
        className='container'
        onMouseMove={e => this.handleMouseMove(e)}
      >
        <div className='cursors'>
          // this below is the main cursor
          // we set its style inline with coordinates from state
          <div 
            className='cursor'
            style={{ 
              left: xMain, 
              top: yMain,
            }}
          />
          
          // this below is the trailing cursor
          <div 
            className='cursor'
            style={{ 
              left: xTrailing, 
              top: yTrailing,
            }}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
* {
    cursor: none;
}

.container {
  background: black;
  min-height: 800px;
}

.cursor {
    position: fixed;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    pointer-events:none;
}

.cursors .cursor:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #3a26fd;
    z-index: 100002;
}
.cursors .cursor:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    z-index: 100001;
    height: 9px;
    width: 9px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>    
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think this gave me a better understanding about react... But I still have one doubt, I suppose for it to work in the whole site I can create a fixed container with height and width of 100%, or is there a way to apply that event to the body? or is there another option to make it work in the whole page? Anyway, thanks, this really helped me out.

Comment: Oh, I set the container to a specific height only to make sure it works here in the pen, any div structure you have setup on your landing page should work and I'd recommend setting the container height and width to 100% anyway, the container div should simply be the outer most div in render method of App.js. However, for it to work properly as a real cursor at all times I suspect hacks including z-indexes and fixed position divs are needed. Don't know until I include in an actual project. Try including it in your project and let me know if it works this way already. :)

Comment: It worked perfectly, had to make a few tricks like you said, with z-indexes and stuff for modals and that, but it worked, thanks, man, this was really helpful!

Answer (score 6):

My solution used requestAnimationFrame instead of setTimeout and refs for smaller paint times and smoother animation, moreover, using transforms instead of absolute position will typically provide better FPS.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      mouseX: 0,
      mouseY: 0,
      trailingX: 0,
      trailingY: 0,
    };
    this.cursor = React.createRef();
    this.cursorTrailing = React.createRef();
    this.animationFrame = null;
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.onMouseMove);
    this.moveCursor();
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.onMouseMove)
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.animationFrame);
  }
  
  onMouseMove = (evt) => {
    const { clientX, clientY } = evt;
    this.setState({
      mouseX: clientX,
      mouseY: clientY,
    });
  }
  
  moveCursor = () => {
    const { mouseX, mouseY, trailingX, trailingY } = this.state;
    const diffX = mouseX - trailingX;
    const diffY = mouseY - trailingY;
    //  Number in expression is coeficient of the delay. 10 for example. You can play with it. 
    this.setState({
      trailingX: trailingX + diffX / 10,
      trailingY: trailingY + diffY / 10,
    },
    () => {
    // Using refs and transform for better performance.
      this.cursor.current.style.transform = `translate3d(${mouseX}px, ${mouseY}px, 0)`;
      this.cursorTrailing.current.style.transform = `translate3d(${trailingX}px, ${trailingY}px, 0)`;
      this.animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(this.moveCursor);
    });
  }
  
  render = () => {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="cursors">
          <div 
            className="cursor"
            ref={this.cursor}
          />
          <div 
            className='cursor'
            ref={this.cursorTrailing}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
* {
    cursor: none;
}

.container {
  background: black;
  min-height: 800px;
}

.cursor {
    position: fixed;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    pointer-events:none;
}

.cursors .cursor:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #3a26fd;
    z-index: 100002;
}
.cursors .cursor:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    z-index: 100001;
    height: 9px;
    width: 9px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>    
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```